# How do I configure log4net to append the datetime at the time of rollover?

Tags: log4net

Here is my appender:

```
  <appender name="ApplicationRollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="logs/application.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
    <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd-hhmmss" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
    <maximumFileSize value="500KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger %C.%M --- %message --- %newlineTrace:%newline %stacktrace%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

What it currently outputs is:

```
application.time-logging-started.1.log
application.time-logging-started.2.log
application.time-logging-started.3.log
```

what I want is:

```
application.time-of-first-rollover.log
application.time-of-second-rollover.log
application.time-of-third-rollover.log
```

can this be done? if so, how?

Comment: Not sure if there is a simple built in way to do this but you could write your own appended by inheriting from the RollingfileAppender and overriding the File param's Set() to do something like `base.File = "programname." + time-stamp + value; And set the file value in the config file to be whatever you want in the file name after the time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your file element is using a PatternString for the file name, the rolling file appender does already use a conversion for name. There is no need to override the default working.

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <file value="logs\" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd-hhmmss'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
  <maximumFileSize value="500KB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: but what if I don't want the current log in the folder?

Comment: Wouldn't that roll the file every second, as the rollingStyle is `Composite`?